# How to reorder table column position in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following table and want to reorder the table column according to the `<th>` position attribute value with jquery after the page is loaded.

I looked at the following solutions but couldn't solve my problem:

1. [jQuery re-ordering table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907333/jquery-re-ordering-table-columns)
2. [Re-order table columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759095/re-order-table-columns)
3. [Change table columns order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464219/change-table-columns-order)

```html
<table>
    <head>
        <tr>
            <th position = "3">Email</th>
            <th position = "1">Name</th>
            <th position = "2">Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </head>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ali@gmail.com</td>
            <td>Hamid</td>
            <td>0776567432</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an object from the position attributes using the `<th>` index as keys.

Then use that object in a `sort()` callback to look up new order for each element

```js
const colOrder = {}

$('thead th').each(function(i){
    colOrder[i] = parseInt( $(this).attr('position') );
});


$('tr').html(function(i){
    return $(this).children().sort(function(a,b){
       const aOrder = colOrder[$(a).index()],
            bOrder = colOrder[$(b).index()];
       return aOrder - bOrder;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th position = "3">Email</th>
            <th position = "1">Name</th>
            <th position = "2">Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ali@gmail.com</td>
            <td>Hamid</td>
            <td>0776567432</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is not working if I run code snippet @charlietfl Please explian